# Maven doesn't find Spark libs installed with brew

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I am new with Maven and Spark and I would like to play a bit with both of them.
I am on OSx so I've installed both using brew. 
On eclipse I created a Maven project with the quick wizard and created the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.and.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

while the main class is:

```
package myapp;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World"); }

}
```

But I get the following error:

> Missing artifact com.sparkjava:spark-core:jar:2.4.3

I thought it was because of the brew installation and so I've add the line:

```
 <systemPath>\usr\local\Cellar\apache-spark\2.4.3\libexec\jars</systemPath>
```

as an explicit path for spark jars just after the version tag in the pom.xml
Until now I have no success.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I verified Maven and Spark installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven is getting the dependencies automatically from the network. If you want it to use locally installed jars, you have to add them to your local maven repository:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

But I am wondering: You could also tell maven to get the spark dependency itself. It seems to be available for maven users:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
So the dependency should be:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of the `system` scope:

> This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

It means that you should provide the path to jar for *each* launch of your code. And for compilation as well (because of import). Change the scope or provide the path to the jar for compiler explicitly.